# How to convert XML to json with jsonSlurperClassic in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I have XML with my code

```
def xml = 
'''
<path>
    <testdata>
        <item>
            <resourceURI>https://localhost/version/</resourceURI>
            <relativePath>/test/folder/version/</relativePath>
            <text>version</text>
            <leaf>false</leaf>
            <lastModifiedtest>2021-07-03</lastModifiedtest>
            <sizeOnDisk>-1</sizeOnDisk>
        </item>
    </testdata>
</path>
'''
```

How to convert this xml to json with jsonSlurperClassic?
I understand that you need to use the toJsonObject method, then call toString() from it and get a json string and pass it to jsonSlurperClassic.
I tried this with Groovy Web Console

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
def xml = 
'''
<path>
    <testdata>
        <item>
            <resourceURI>https://localhost/version/</resourceURI>
            <relativePath>/test/folder/version/</relativePath>
            <text>version</text>
            <leaf>false</leaf>
            <lastModifiedtest>2021-07-03</lastModifiedtest>
            <sizeOnDisk>-1</sizeOnDisk>
        </item>
    </testdata>
</path>
'''
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
String jsonPrettyPrintString = json.toString(4);
System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
```

But I get an error: unable to resolve class JSONObject
What am I doing wrong?
Link: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5119690196123648

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I have added the necessary information to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using an external dependency. You can use `Grape` to `@Grab` the dependency when you run a script on your own machine (but be aware that web consoles normally do not allow Grape to download files).

```java
@Grab(group='org.json', module='json', version='20210307')
import org.json.XML

String xml = '''\
<path>
    <testdata>
        <item>
            <resourceURI>https://localhost/version/</resourceURI>
            <relativePath>/test/folder/version/</relativePath>
            <text>version</text>
            <leaf>false</leaf>
            <lastModifiedtest>2021-07-03</lastModifiedtest>
            <sizeOnDisk>-1</sizeOnDisk>
        </item>
    </testdata>
</path>''';

println XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString(4)
```

The output will be

```js
{"path": {"testdata": {"item": {
    "relativePath": "/test/folder/version/",
    "resourceURI": "https://localhost/version/",
    "text": "version",
    "leaf": false,
    "sizeOnDisk": -1,
    "lastModifiedtest": "2021-07-03"
}}}}
```

*(`JsonSlurper` and `JsonSlurperClassic` are not used as they are meant for reading JSON, and not for reading XML nor writing JSON)*

Comment: The problem is also that this xml is constantly updated and the script must output all the values of the fields in json.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I make a request to a resource that gives me the xml that I wrote in the description, but there is a lot of information, several blocks with fields. Write lines after assert XML.tojsonobject(xml).toString(4) == '''\ .... Very expensive. You need to use toJsonObject, then call toString() from it and get a json string, pass it to JsonSlurper.

Comment: My answer originally had an `assert` statement that I included to show the result. I have now replaced this with `println` to mirror the question, and included the output in a separate block to make this clearer for you (@ArtemKiryanov).

Comment: Thansk for help me!